# Why are emails being sent from the wrong store from the command line

Tags: email, email-templates, locale

We have a script that is sending emails via the command line. Since we are using the email templates we are loading them using the `Mage::getModel('core/email_template')` model and then calling `->send()`.

This results in the emails being sent with the wrong store information and locale inside.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the `Mage::getModel('core/email_template')` loads the design information using `Mage_Core_Model_Template::_applyDesignConfig()` which intern loads a store via `Mage::getDesign()->getStore()`. When you follow this down the rabbit hole you will see the following.

```
public function getStore()
{
    if ($this->_store === null) {
        return Mage::app()->getStore();
    }
    return $this->_store;
}
```

This means that if the store is not set if will load the default store, note that nothing is being passed into the `getStore` call.

So one way around this is to call `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(22)` but as pointed out by [Sander](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/50/sander-mangel) there is a better way.

You can use `Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation')` to wrap your code in store emulation.

```
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');

//Start environment emulation of the specified store
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

// Your code here

//Stop environment emulation and restore original store
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

For more information see [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/emulate-store-in-magento/)

Comment: Better to wrap it in an emulator: http://inchoo.net/magento/emulate-store-in-magento/